# erlang debugger crashes when mouse is moved

Tags: debugging, erlang

I tried to use erlang debugger, but it crashes every time I put the mouse over a window. Error message is generated:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 13-Jan-2014::18:39:52 ===
Error in process <0.45.0> with exit value:
{badarith,[{dbg_ui_mon_win,handle_event,2,[{file,"dbg_ui_mon_win.erl"},
{line,464}]},{dbg_ui_mon,loop,1,[{file,"dbg_ui_mon.erl"},{line,230}]}]}
```

I tried to reinstall erlang, but it didn't help. I'm using Linux Mint 15.

Comment: To save someone a few clicks, [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/0481ecafa24dc60c6bca8afdda038dc2239c991d/lib/debugger/src/dbg_ui_mon_win.erl#L461-L464) is the location of the crash.

Comment: I reported the bug: https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-789

Answer (score 0):

Yes so using latest R16B03 commit, [error is here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/25237481ccccd3ddfa74582dc267632ad618ba30/lib/debugger/src/dbg_ui_mon_win.erl#L464) (note `gs:read/2` calls)

and can come from arithmetics with atoms given that those functions *can* [return atoms here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/25237481ccccd3ddfa74582dc267632ad618ba30/lib/gs/src/gs.erl#L133-L138)

as they are used in `gs:read/2` definition [a bit above](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/25237481ccccd3ddfa74582dc267632ad618ba30/lib/gs/src/gs.erl#L116-L117).

That's all I found out. That should be reported.